# Cosmos v4 SDK Java: Query Execution takes time when the application starts

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to CosmosDB and using v4 SDK Java. Query execution takes time when the application starts. For few of them I have observed the turn around time in the query metrics to be around 10 sec. It gets stable in less than a minute. My application runs on the Kubernetes pod.
How can I improve the query execution time during the application start up?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with specifics (code, Request Units from your results, etc). Also, are you executing your code from the same region your Cosmos DB instance is in? Right now, your question has too many open-ended questions, as written; there's no way to know what issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This latency is caused by the SDK client making its initial connections to the service. The only way to improve the performance is to keep the application alive between requests and not perform a cold start every time. Or if adding additional instances, allow the instance a few seconds to initialize before issuing queries against it. The application should keep a singleton reference to the cosmos client in scope for the life of the application as well as references to every container being called.

There are many other performance tips and tricks you can implement as well. See, [Best practices for Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/best-practice-java) and [Performance tips for Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-java-sdk-v4-sql?tabs=api-async)